# Dynamic preload of Audio elements

Tags: javascript, html

On initial page load, there are audio elements on the page which have `preload="metadata"`. Dynamically, I update that preload attribute to `"Auto"`, and I am wondering, does it actually preload the audio file when doing it this way? (or if you don't know maybe you know of a way I can verify it?)

Comment: From the [preload attribute doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp): _"The preload attribute allows the author to **provide a hint** to the browser about what he/she **thinks** will lead to the best user experience. **This attribute may be ignored in some instances.**"_. In Chrome, for example, the file is loaded whether you use `metadata` or `auto`. So, technically, you can't be sure you'll have the same behavior in every browser.

Comment: Yeah, but the docs don't write about the attribute being changed dynamically later on after the Audio element has already been added and I wonder if it makes a difference.

Comment: It does _if the browser decides to follow it_, check this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbquhz2/), it will wait 2 seconds, and go from `none` to `auto`, dynamically. In Chrome, it loads the file, but in other browsers, I don't know.